# Transcoding video in UWP

Tags: ffmpeg, uwp, vlc, mjpeg, transcode

I need to transcode video streaming from MJPEG to MP4, AVI or MKV format. Is it possible to do with ffmpeg or vlc? I am developing UWP Win10 app and there aren't many packages for this.

Edit: my code

```
        VLCPreview.Source = "http://Admin:123456@192.168.0.21:6021/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?GET_STREAM";

   /cmd/encoder?GET_STREAM

        try
        {


                            HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                            aHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Admin", "123456");
                            aHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

                            HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient(aHandler);
                            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                                                                                    //url get stream o web.Source
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await aClient.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.21:6021/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?GET_STREAM", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);//urlLinkToOnlineStream

                            Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                             IInputStream inputStream = stream.AsInputStream();
                             ulong totalBytesRead = 0;
                             while (true)
                             {
                                 // Read from the web.
                                 IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(4096);
                                 buffer = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
                                 if (buffer.Length == 0)
                                 {
                                     break;
                                 }
                                 totalBytesRead += buffer.Length;
                                 await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
                                Debug.WriteLine("TotalBytesRead: {0:f}", totalBytesRead);

                                if (StopRec == true) { break;}
            }

            transcode(destinationFile, sampleFileVidTranscoded);

                              inputStream.Dispose();

                            fileStream.Dispose();
```

Comment: You sure can use ffmpeg but you also should try to better write your question.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, uwp app has its own namespace [`Windows.Media.Transcoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Transcoding) for transcoding video. For how to transcode media files please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files). And the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaTranscoding) provide examples for transcoding media files to `MP4`,`WMI` and `AVI` that you can reference.

Secondly, For FFmpeg, it is a free, open-source multimedia framework that includes a set of tools which can be used by end users for **transcoding**, streaming, and playing, as well as a set of libraries for developers to use in applications. So you could use it for transcoding. Fortunately, currently there is a FFmpeg library for uwp called "FFmpegInterop". You can try to use it by the Nuget package [FFmpegInterop.UWP 1.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFmpegInterop.UWP/), and more details please reference [Using FFmpeg in Windows Applications](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/#LHyi1FgBXlBuPPoX.97).

For VLC, there is also a package for uwp, it is [VLC.MediaElement](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement). You could access this package by reference [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VLC.MediaElement).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!. I used Windows.Media.Transcoding, but when it creates MediaEncodingProfile , it crashes throwing the following exception: System.TypeloadException {"Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile' is not registered.":"Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile"}. Any ideas?, I searched and I didn´t fount anything.

Comment: @cahernanz please provide your code snippet. And please ensure you have import the relative name space. Additionally,  accepted an answer and open a new thread will be much better since this is a new issue.

Comment: Furthermore, the code i edited, it creates the uncompressed file that weights "x" MBs, but i can´t play It. I need to "pass" though ffmpeg.exe to play it correctly. Any ideas for solving it?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if my video is in mjpeg format, there is many problems to play it. I cant play with vlc. I think i can´t convert from mjpeg to another formats using mediaTranscoding, insn´t it?